# How to catch PayPalConnectionException?

Tags: php, paypal

I can't seem to catch the PayPalConnectionException in PayPal-PHP-SDK. I used an example from PayPal-PHP-SDK Github Wiki page and my code looks like this:

```
<?php

require 'start.php';

use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

$serverName = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


if(!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])){
    header("Location: $serverName/cancel");
    exit();
}

if((bool)$_GET['success'] === false){
    header("Location: $serverName/cancel");
    exit();
}

$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerID = $_GET['PayerID'];

$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);

$execute = new PaymentExecution();
$execute->setPayerId($payerID);

try{
    $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
    header("Location: $serverName/payments/success");
    //exit();
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
    die($ex);
} catch(Execption $e){
    $data = json_decode($e->getData());
    header("Location: $serverName/payments/failed.php?err=" . $data->message);
    //echo $data->message;
    die($e);
}
```

For some reason it still outputs an uncaught exception error. Here are my logs:

```
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143454 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PayPal\\Exception\\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 404 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-19837119W5913913TLEJMYYQ.' in /home/root/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/payments/PayPal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:177
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143805 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143819 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/root/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/payments/PayPal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(73): PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('')
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143831 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /home/root/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/payments/PayPal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\\Transport\\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'GET', '', NULL)
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143841 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /home/root/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/payments/PayPal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(603): PayPal\\Common\\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'GET', '', NULL, Object(PayPal\\Rest\\ApiContext), NULL)
[Sat May 13 18:57:24.143853 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29736:tid 139778838230784] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /home/root/domains/ in /home/root/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/payments/PayPal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 177
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess the error occurs on a line outside the "try{" block. Maybe on the line: 

Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal); ?

Which line does the exception point to as the origin of the error in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
    header("Location: $serverName/payments/success");
    //exit();
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    **echo $ex->getMessage(); // Prints the detailed error message** 
    die($ex);
} catch(Execption $e){
    $data = json_decode($e->getData());
    header("Location: $serverName/payments/failed.php?err=" . $data->message);
    //echo $data->message;
    die($e);
}
```

Comment: What does that do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no using for PayPalConnectionException class before your class declaration, you should use the full namespace.

Try changing

```
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
```

to

```
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
```